# Reasons why an IntentService won't start?

Tags: android, service, android-intent, intentservice

I have an Android IntentService that is behaving strangely.  I am sending it an intent via a call to startService(intent).

(I apologize, I'm away from my desk and can't paste any actual code.)

When I make the above call nothing happens.  Neither the constructor nor the onHandleIntent methods are called in the Intent Service.  There are no compiler warnings or errors and I see nothing of interest in the Console or Log.

As I continue to investigate this, I was just wondering if there is a short list of likely reasons why an IntentService would not start like this with no obvious evidence of why.  Is the problem likely in the manifest file?

Comment: Post code that you use to call `startService()` and post the manifest entry for your service. It is likely that one or the other is broken.

Comment: You're right. I had a typo in the name of the class in the manifest file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that you need to take a closer look at LogCat. Common problems here include:

- failed to list the service in the manifest
- failed to create a public zero-argument constructor on the service (the default constructor for `IntentService` takes one argument, and you need to add your own constructor)
- other syntactical problems (e.g., service is declared `abstract`)

However, all of those will result in messages in LogCat. I can think of no scenario under which `startService()` would not invoke your code without a message in LogCat.

Comment: You were right.  I had a filter enabled and was missing the critical log telling me the class couldn't be found.  Turned out to be simple typo in my Manifest file.  Thanks for the help!